# How can we export translatable fields content in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, translation, odoo-16

In Odoo (16), I would like to export all my translatable fields content to a file so I can easily edit it and translate to new languages.
I already know how to edit one by one, in the screen, but for what is a growing set of data it will take more time that translate it using a proper program (example: PoEdit).

Here is part of my model definition

```
class Card(models.Model):

    _name = "carddecks.card"
    _description = "Card"
    cardText = fields.Char("Card Text", required=True, translate=True)
```

And now I can also see the language icon in the Card form, so I can edit it there.

How do I manage to export a po file with all the content?
All I can get from Settings -> Translations -> Export Translation is a set of field labels. Not field content...

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you find a proper solution, I have the same challenge?

Comment: @Perino only the export import as explained in a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

In `debug mode` via `Technical Settings` there should be a menu item named `Translated Terms`

Comment: Are you refering to Odoo 16 community edition? I cannot find such menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to translate data in bulk. It isn't the best way I think it should be done, but it seems to work.
We can use the default Odoo import/export data for this, while we make sure that in the user preferences, we have selected the language to which we wish to translate the data to.

So, imagine the first time you created/imported data, it was in English, and you want to translate to Portuguese.

1. Access Odoo backend
2. Click on the user name on the top right corner and click Preferences
3. Choose the language to which you want to translate data, save, and logout/login again and notice the menus are in the language you just chose.
4. Go to the list view of the model whose data we wish to
   translate.
5. Select all the records (or filter the records we wish
   to translate).
6. Go to Actions -> Export Data. Check the box in
   the top left of the popup "I want to update data (import-compatible
   export").
7. Choose the export format (xlsx or csv)
8. Click Export
9. Open your file with your favorite editor (I like LibreOffice)
10. Translate all the fields you wish to translate and save your file
11. Go back to the list view of the translated model and click Favorites, right below the search box and next to the Group By option.
12. Click Import records and then in the button Upload File
13. Choose your file and import it !
14. In order to confirm everything worked fine, edit a record of your translated model, and in the form view, next to the translatable field, in the right, click  the language icon and confirm you have now both English and your language (or as many languages you have active).